# Best way to separate rock fragments in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to make a program to calculate the size distribution of rock fragments based on images from a conveyor belt. I can only achieve that by image segmentation and labeling. Unfortunately, my results are not satisfactory because the program has a problem with dark spots on rock fragments. These spots are incorrectly recognized as edges of the fragments (e.g in the left top corner program found a lot of small fragments, where in reality this is just one big fragment. Did anyone deal with a problem like that?

What I tried until now:

- Canny edge detector
- thresholding with various parameters
- findContours in opencv
- sharpening / bilateral filtering
- meijering, sato, frangi, hessian ridge detectors from skimage.filters - I'm not sure if I used them in a proper way - maybe someone has more experience with these and know how to find parameters that would fit.
- opening/closing (dilate, erode) with different kernels
- current approach: opening -> finding background area -> finding foreground area -> subtracting background and foreground area -> watershed.

code for the current approach:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage import data, util, filters, color, measure
from skimage.segmentation import watershed, clear_border
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import img_as_ubyte


name = 'cut.png'
img = cv2.imread(name, 0)
img_color_org = cv2.imread(name)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel2 = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
kernel3 = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)

opening = cv2.morphologyEx(
    thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel2, iterations=1)

sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel3, iterations=3)

dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 3)

ret2, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(
    dist_transform, 0.15*dist_transform.max(), 255, 0)
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)

unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)

ret3, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)
markers = markers + 10
markers[unknown == 255] = 0
markers = cv2.watershed(img_color_org, markers)
img_color_org[markers == -1] = [0, 0, 255]

img2 = color.label2rgb(markers, bg_label=0)
cv2.imwrite('img.png', img_color_org)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: pure image]Original Image

[image: before watershed] Image after background subtraction, and before watershed operation

[image: current algorithm segmentation] Watershed applied to the original image

[image: hand-made Segmentation in paint] hand-made segmentation with desired edges

[image: Original image with better quality]Original image with better quality

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: looks like a very challenging task to me, probably kot solvable here.

Comment: echoing @Micka and adding that it might help to look at some CNN segmentation models.

Comment: The original image has very low quality also.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I've added other image with slightly better quality

Comment: @QuangHoang It requires a lot of training data, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be able to separate those rocks by hand even. Any change you can improve the illumination? Any chance you can use some form of 3D imaging?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Unfortunately, that's the only thing I got.

Comment: @nathancy I tried HED and it worked even worse ;/

Comment: maybe you can try to reduce darkspots on rock fragments by applying blur > dilate > blur again.

Comment: If size distribution is what you looking for, might consider pipeline: non-local-means denoising -> foreground-background segmentation -> distance map. From local maxima of the distance map, you can approximate the radius of the rock fragment with some confidence without explicit rock segmentation

Comment: The 3D imaging idea above was best imo, but if not available, you could use a few flood lamps of differing color pointing across the conveyor in different directions, with a camera aimed straight down. (or if you can get a few cheap non-spectra cameras, then pair them with a flood lamp of the same band) Then filter for each color or band individually, desaturate to gray, and then create a composite overlay of all 3 images. Basically creating a 'mask' for each band.  **and hopefully, at least one of the lamps will fill in the holes / react with dark spots.

Comment: Assuming it is your conveyor belt... can you add another information source (sensor)? As an example infrared imaging or radar etc. Every additional source of information will bring your error rate down. Then feed them into a training model.

Comment: Actually, from the image, what is a "rock fragment"? Some particles that looks like several individuals to our brain may still be recognized as one unique individual in your rock population by almost any computer vision algorithm.